# How do I send a different subdomain to a different IP, if two IPs are on the same VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ip, vps

I have a VPS with three IPs. They're all on completely unrelated IPs (one is `23.226.xxx.x`, another is `107.161.xx.xx`, a third is `167.88.xxx.xx`).

If I go to `beta.mydomain.com` (for example, that won't actually be the subdomain), I want it to go to `23.226.xxx.x`. Going to `mydomain.com` would just go to `107.161.xx.xx`, and going to `somethingelse.mydomain.com` would go to `167.88.xxx.xx`.

Is this possible?

Comment: One-word answers are somewhat discouraged here and I don't think you would find "Yes" to be very helpful.  Could you add to your question what you have tried already and what problems you ran into?

Comment: @Ladadadada I'm not asking if I can do it, I'm asking how. Does that fix it or is it still against the rules?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create 3 different A records in your DNS service pointing the domain or subdomains to the different ip addresses and then in apache create 3 different virtual hosts (one per domain/subdomain) bound each to its respective ip.

A reason to do this would be to use https, otherwise it's not needed in general since you can serve multiple domains and subdomains from the same ip address.